# Ibexa Graphql error : Could not find type with alias "RepositoryLanguage"

Tags: ezpublish, ibexa

I have this error when showing any content in  the backend of IBEXA (formerly ezpublish) :

```
Could not find type with alias "RepositoryLanguage". Did you forget to define it?
```

I tried clearing the cache with `php bin/console cache:clear` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to (re)generate your domain schema. with those commands :

```
php bin/console ibexa:graphql:generate-schema
php bin/console cache:clear
```

For more information
visit the docs on : https://doc.ibexa.co/en/latest/api/graphql/graphql/#setup